Corpse Princess seasons
I watched "Corpse Princess" a couple weeks ago, and I was blown away by how good it was. I didn't expect much, since the name is so cheesy. At the end I wanted more, but it didn't seem available on Crunchyroll. As far as I can tell there are seasons past the initial corpse princess anime available on Crunchyroll, does anyone know how many seasons, episodes, and/or movies of corpse princess exist, and what there watch order is?

Currently there are 2 seasons, a DVD only Special and a OVA available for corpse-princess.
The release order is as follows, and as far as I can tell without watching it, should also be the chronological order to watch it.

Season 1: Shikabane Hime: Aka
Season 2: Shikabane Hime: Kuro
OVA: Shikabane Hime: Kuro – Soredemo, Hito to Shite
Dvd special Shikabane Hime: Puchitto

Both seasons and the OVA seem to be available on Crunchyroll (and previously on Prime Video). The Dvd special however does not seem to be available on any of those, and may require you to buy a physical copy to view legally.

The Petite special was part of disc 4 of the original JP DVD release of Kuro
